# Multiple Selectors With hasClass() Issues

Tags: jquery

I'm am trying to write some jQuery that has multiple selectors & multiple hasClass.

Basically, there are multiple elements that could have various class names. Any combination thereof, should append the google font.

```
if ($('nav.main-navigation, header.site-header, main.site-content, footer.site-footer').hasClass('header-menu-font-shojumaru', 'header-title-font-shojumaru', 'header-tagline-font-shojumaru', 'body-font-shojumaru', 'body-heading-font-shojumaru', 'body-widget-title-font-shojumaru', 'footer-font-shojumaru')) {
    $('head').append('<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shojumaru" rel="stylesheet">');
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working like I thought it would. It working seems to appear random, although I know it's not. I cannot figure out what the problem is and how to correct it.

Comment: Why was this post deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific case can be achieved by `is()`, and treating them like a selector.

```
if ($('nav.main-navigation, header.site-header, main.site-content, footer.site-footer').is('.header-menu-font-shojumaru, .header-title-font-shojumaru, .header-tagline-font-shojumaru, .body-font-shojumaru, .body-heading-font-shojumaru, .body-widget-title-font-shojumaru, .footer-font-shojumaru')) {
    $('head').append('<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shojumaru" rel="stylesheet">');
}
```

[Official docs for `is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)